# Understanding total supply in uniswap v2 pair

Tags: uniswap, defi

I'm trying to understand the notion of decimals in total supply in a Uniswap v2 pair.

Taking eg,
if we have two **18** decimal tokens.

Adding Liquidity:
token0: **500000000000000000000** (500 tokens)
token1: **300000000000000000000** (300 tokens)

totalSupply will be **387298334620741688517** (approx **387** tokens, considering **18** decimals)

Now, if we use a different decimal token. Like USDC(**6** decimals), and do the same process

token0: **500000000000000000000** (**500** tokens with **18** decimals)
token1: **300000000** (**300** tokens with **6** decimals)

totalSupply will be **387298334620741**.

Now, what is the notion of decimals here?

is it,
**0.000387298334620741** considering **18** decimals

or

**387** tokens with **12** decimals.

If the first one is true, then adding a liquidity of (500+300) has just given me a 0.00038 LP supply?

Thanks!

Comment: what, where are you getting 387 from? show your math

Comment: @johnny5 
adding liquidity of 500 token0(18 decimals) and 300 token1(6 decimals) will give a total supply for the LP as 387298334620741.
Now 387298334620741/10**18  (as uni LP has 18 decimals) = 0.000387298334620741 . So does that mean, after adding liquidity of (500+300) tokens, i just got 0.000387 LP supply?

Answer (score 2):

To understand the math better I suggest looking at the code directly:
https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol

Factory initializes the base value or the LP token via the functions

```
function initialize(address _token0, address _token1) external {
    require(msg.sender == factory, 'UniswapV2: FORBIDDEN'); // sufficient check
    token0 = _token0;
    token1 = _token1;
}
```

and

```
function mint(address to) external lock returns (uint liquidity) {
    (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
    uint balance0 = IERC20(token0).balanceOf(address(this));
    uint balance1 = IERC20(token1).balanceOf(address(this));
    uint amount0 = balance0.sub(_reserve0);
    uint amount1 = balance1.sub(_reserve1);

    bool feeOn = _mintFee(_reserve0, _reserve1);
    uint _totalSupply = totalSupply; // gas savings, must be defined here since totalSupply can update in _mintFee
    if (_totalSupply == 0) {
        liquidity = Math.sqrt(amount0.mul(amount1)).sub(MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY);
       _mint(address(0), MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY); // permanently lock the first MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY tokens
    } else {
        liquidity = Math.min(amount0.mul(_totalSupply) / _reserve0, amount1.mul(_totalSupply) / _reserve1);
    }
    require(liquidity > 0, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY_MINTED');
    _mint(to, liquidity);

    _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
    if (feeOn) kLast = uint(reserve0).mul(reserve1); // reserve0 and reserve1 are up-to-date
    emit Mint(msg.sender, amount0, amount1);
}
```

These functions combined add the liquidity to the contract and then mints the returned LP tokens to *_to* and then updates the LP reserves.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out @fudgydrs 
After reviewing the code, my observations are, the decimals for the pair are **18**, and the **totalSupply** depends upon the basic formula 
`liquidity = Math.sqrt(amount0.mul(amount1)).sub(MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY);`

so considering the 18 decimals for token0 and 6 decimals for token 1, the sqrt function will give 12 (sqrt(18+6)) decimals for the final outcome. But it will be represented in 18 decimals. Am i right?

Comment: Correct, uinswapv2pair keeps the 18 decimals for the LP tokens.